# Why invocation bean failed error while initializing springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to setup the rabbitmq connection factory in class. Would like to read the property defined in application.properties file using @Value annotation. However, somehow bean configuration is not correct. I am not able to understand that .
Here is the code :

```
@Controller
@Configuration
@RequestMapping("/unittestdata")
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class UnitAmqpRestController {


    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}")
    public static int mqPort;

    public UnitAmqpRestController() {

    }
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnitAmqpRestController.class);

    private static RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private String replyQueueName;

    private static Connection connection;
    private static Channel channel;
    private String requestQueueName = "rpc_queue_unit";

    public UnitAmqpRestController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, String replyQueueName, Connection connection, Channel channel, String requestQueueName) {

        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        this.replyQueueName = replyQueueName;
        this.connection = connection;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.replyQueueName = requestQueueName;

    }

    @PostConstruct  
    public static void main() throws Exception {

        rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(15_000L);
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(getHostProperty());

        factory.setPort(mqPort);
        connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();

    }


    public static String getHostProperty() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.properties");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            properties.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return properties.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.host");

    }
```

here is the error :

> 2019-06-18 10:58:02.642  INFO 29037 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2019-06-18 10:58:02.661  INFO 29037 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-06-18
>   10:58:02.667 ERROR 29037 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'unitAmqpRestController': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at com.infy.ci.unitamqpservice.UnitamqpserviceApplication.main(UnitamqpserviceApplication.java:10)
>   [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at com.infy.ci.unitamqpservice.UnitAmqpRestController.main(UnitAmqpRestController.java:69)
>   ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           ... 26 common frames omitted

Not getting whether issue is in constructor OR in the main method ?? 
Am I missing something like @Bean configuration ??

Please suggest

Comment: This will simply never work. You cannot use `@Value` on static fields. You need the rabbit template to be available for the controller to be constructed but you are creating it inside the controller. Next you are also reading the  properties yourself. In short you are working against/around the framework instead of actually using it. Spring Boot already creates the `ConnectionFactory`, `RabbitTemplate` etc. for you, don't do it yourself. Remove all that stuff from the controller and only leave the `@controller` and `@RequestMapping`. There also appears to be nothing exposed in the controller.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please post the modified code ?

Comment: Just remove the class. Spring Boot will configure all of the Rabbit stuff (assuming you have addes `spring-boot-starter-amqp` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks M.Deinum for his comment and post. 
i referred the detailed doc on the

> spring-boot-starter-amqp

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-amqp

it clearly mention on how is not necessary to handle the rabbitmq connection factory on my own. by having standard key parameters defined in application.properties file, AmQPTemplate does everything.

Thanks